# How to mount Windows partition on boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I'd like a GUI method to set my Windows partition to mount on boot, using the same options as when it mounts by me opening it in nautilus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install ntfs-Config Tool from Software Center

Alternatively you can use MountManager , also available from the Software Center

Comment: ntfs3g-config doesn't exist. ntfs-config does but doesn't seem to do what I want at all.

Comment: well it does mount the ntfs volume at boot without the need for you tu manually mount it everytime you boot into ubuntu

Comment: I see, just adding the entries in the app adds them to fstab. Slightly unexpected but it works. It's a shame there's not a simple tick box of "mount this drive on boot" anywhere. Thanks for the help!