# How to automatically mount a partition or drive on program launch?

Tags: mount, banshee, automount

When I launch (start) the program Banshee, I want Ubuntu to automatically mount a particular unmounted partition.

- I don't want to mount this partition at boot time or upon login

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mount Windows partition on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22234/how-to-mount-windows-partition-on-boot)

Comment: @papukaija: No, the OP specifies that he/she does not want to mount the partition on boot. He/She just wants that it is mounted just before running Banshee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the device identifier for the Windows partition. Open a terminal window, maximize it and run:

```
sudo blkid -olist
```

Take note of the value on the `device` column for the Windows partition which contains the music. (This can be of the form `/dev/sda2` for example.)

Run the following:

```
cd  && mkdir bin
```

Then open gedit and type (or copy-paste) the following for Ubuntu versions < 13.10 (I think)

```
#!/bin/sh

udisks --mount /dev/sdXY
banshee --redirect-log --play-enqueued $@
```

for versions >= 13.10, use this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY
banshee --redirect-log --play-enqueued $@
```

To be sure just check which of the packages `udisks` or `udisks2` is installed. You can check this with the command `apt-cache policy <packagename>`, or just try running `udisks` or `udisksctl` and see the response (if the command is available it should print a help message).

Where `/dev/sdXY` is the value you got for your Windows partition. Save it in `/home/your-username/bin` as `banshee-script`

---

Open the file `/home/your-username/.bashrc` in gedit and add the line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

to the end of the file.

---

Now copy and paste into a terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/banshee-script
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
cp  /usr/share/applications/banshee.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications
gedit  ~/.local/share/applications/banshee.desktop
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Substitute the `Exec=` line with:

```
Exec=/home/your-username/bin/banshee-script %U
```

Save it, reboot and try running Banshee (from the Dash) without mounting the Windows partition.

---

**Remark**

It might be the case that you've set your Music folder to be `/media/your-username/windows-partition/path/to/music`. So you should go to Banshee's preferences and reset it to `/media/windows-partition/path/to/music`, then rescan your library (`Tools > Rescan Music Library`).

Comment: it worked but it didnt work! i rebooted, opened nautilus, started banshee, and on banshee start i saw in nautilus that the partition got mounted. but in banshee when i tried to play a song it didnt work/couldnt access the file. i had to unmount and mount again before banshee could access the song.

Comment: I've made a correction, please try again. (In the line that says `echo 'PATH=...'`)

Comment: still doesnt work. the wait 5 didnt work either

Comment: I've made another edit, please check it. Are you sure that the right partition is being mounted? If so in Banshee's preferences, in the **Source specific** tab, choose the folder which contains your music (i.e., `/media/windows-partition/music-folder`). Then rescan your library `Tools > Rescan Music Library`.

Comment: im sure it is the right partition.. as i said, after i unmount and mount the exact same partition banshee plays, i dont even have to reopen banshee.. on unmounting i get the message "is mounted by another user" and a prompt to enter sudo pw to be able to unmount, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: No, the problem is that `udisks` will mount your Windows partition in `/media/windows-partition`, but Nautilus mounts it in `/media/your-username/windows-partition`. That is also why remounting works. So please do as I say in my previous comment. (Unmount the partition, open Banshee and check the partition is remounted, then choose your music folder and rescan). You can remove the `wait 5` line from the script too.

Comment: ok, seems to work, will confirm in a few minutes after rescaning is done xD good to know what the problem is!